# How do I remove the language_content_entity query from the canonical URL?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Following the [Translating content](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/multilingual/translating-content) documentation we have setup our site to have `Spanish`, `English`, and `Japanese`. When we are adding, editing, deleting, and publishing pages in different languages we have no issues. However, when we view the canonical url, we find that the `language_content_entity=en` is added for `English` pages, for example. We are already adding the `hreflang` to each page so don't need this extra parameter in the `canonical`.

For all English pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.somedomain.net/some/path?language_content_entity=en">
```

For all Spanish pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.somedomain.net/some/path?language_content_entity=es">
```

How can we remove the `language_content_entity=en` from the `canonical` url?

Comment: When you use the language detection method Session and a user doesn't have a session, the detection falls back to a query parameter.

Comment: The method "Content language" adds a query parameter, too, which seems to be the one you have in your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make canonical URL in document HEAD absolute](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263077/make-canonical-url-in-document-head-absolute)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove specific meta-tag from header section of page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247799/how-to-remove-specific-meta-tag-from-header-section-of-page)

Comment: The above questions will give you answers on how to alter certain meta tags, including canonical links.

Comment: @leymannx i reviewed the first link and that is separate from my question. i am already doing `[node:url:absolute]` for the canonical. the second link is different from my question. i want to remove the portion from the URL, but the second link is for removing an entire `meta-tag`

Comment: The place where you remove it, is the place where you also simply can change it.

Comment: And it also seems you are using the metatag module. Then you should follow the first link. You see the `rtrim($href, '/');`? That's when the existing canonical URL simply gets stripped of a trailing slash. You can strip your unwanted strings from it **the exact same way**.

Comment: I vote to close the question because it is unclear whether it is about altering metatags in general or about a specific query string added to outbound urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illustrate once again what you are supposed to do with the first duplicate question's [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263094/15055):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {

  foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $head) {

    if ((isset($head[1]) ? $head[1] : FALSE) == 'canonical_url') {

      $href = isset($head[0]['#attributes']['href']) ? $head[0]['#attributes']['href'] : FALSE;

      if ($href) {
        // Strip ?language_content_entity=en from the end of the URL if exists.
        $href = rtrim($href, '?language_content_entity=en');
        // Strip ?language_content_entity=es from the end of the URL if exists.
        $href = rtrim($href, '?language_content_entity=es');
        // Then set the new value.
        $attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$key][0]['#attributes']['href'] = $href;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this may work for small set of languages, but the moment we go with more than languages i would have to add more lines with `$href = rtrim($href, 'language');`. Let me test a regex to see if i can get this to work.

Comment: @usernameabc – That is up to you. Or you find a different way how to avoid the query gets added in the first place. And use a different logic maybe to fire certain features that are bound to this query. You asked for how to strip a certain string from the canonical URL. And this is the answer. `:-)`

Comment: @usernameabc – Or you provide your own custom tokens. But then you also probably will end up with a similar pattern.

Comment: Note that the question is asking specifically about removing language_content_entity query string. The best way to do that is to change the order of the language negotiation mechanism (see @4k4 comment in question). The proposed solution here may work but is far from ideal

Comment: @Pere – Ah yeah, I see. I was misguided by the metatag question tag. You should consider adding a proper answer that explains how to do that exactly.