# Remove string from [node:url] and node alias

Tags: 8, hooks, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

**Background**

- We have enabled `content translation` where we detect based on the content language. This allows us to translate properly as needed, but it has a bad side effect.
- It will not only add `?language_content_entity=en` to the canonical `metatag`, but if we have any links that return node URLs, it will also append `?language_content_entity=en`. This happens for both `logged in` and `anonymous` users.
- Under the `metatag` settings for each content type we are using the `[node:url:absolute]` token for any path field and that also returns `?language_content_entity=en` in the `URL`.
- On the `/admin/config/regional/language/detection`, under `Content Language Detection` we have the following `Detection Methods` enabled in order.

  1. `Content Language`
  2. `Cookies`
  3. `Selected Language`

[image: content language detection]

**Question**

How can we remove `?language_content_entity=en` string from the `node's path alias` and `[node:url:absolute]` token?

**What we tried:**

1. In order to remove the `?language_content_entity=en` from the `canonical` url, we used the `best answer` from [How to override canonical URL?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271352/how-to-override-canonical-url).
2. tried using [hook_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.6.x), but it did not find method to remove string from URL.

**Only set methods I can see when I do the following:**

```
function mymodule_link_alter(&$variables) {
  ksm($variables['url']);
}
```

[image: hook link alter]

Example:

[image: unami spanish selection]

Comment: "We have enabled content translation where we detect based on the URL. This allows us to translate properly as needed, but it has a bad side effect." Are you sure you don't have other detection methods enabled?

Comment: @4k4 Added screenshot of the settings under `Content Language Detection`. We essentially have 3 enabled. The issue regarding the `?language_content_entity=en` does not exist when `Content Language` is set to `true`